# BLEU score for generation task

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

after I generate the new text using LSTM or RNN how can I measure the quality of the new text.can i use BLEU score?, but BLEU is used to evaluate the line-to-line generation task which focuses on the semantic relevance between two lines. here I do not have the target to compare between two sentences because I totally got a new text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLEU score can only be used to evaluate candidate text outputs against one or more reference outputs.

It's not at all clear from your question what kind of text generation task you're attempting. If you're training an RNN language model on monolingual data and sampling sentences from it, you could evaluate it by using your LM to compute perplexity on a test document that you know is well-written.